# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory...Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtElLuzjA0U

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 -  Whenever I implement "implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.6.1'"  I get this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> 
element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-22:19 to override.
```

When I first did this tutorial, everything compiled and I was able to acquire the progress bar, but when I tried debugging and building, it crashed. Now, my second time around, implementing the dependency gives me the same error.

PS - I have it set to 4.4 - current android

I've looked at "https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages"  and when I cross reference, it seems I'm already including 28.0.0 -  I'm not sure what to do from here.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

/*third party  library*/
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.6.1'

}
```

What support does it need?  I tried implementing  tools:replace...But it just gives me a slew of errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because your project has different versions of the same library - androidx and pre-androidx. 
In android studio tool bar go to: `Refactor-> Migrate to androidX... -> Migrate`

Comment: Could you tell me how to do the whole process?  I'm very new to android studio

Comment: Just press migrate and than `do refactor` int the bottom menu when its appears

Comment: Yes, for anyone else who has this problem, in the top menu, select Refactor > migrate to Android X

Answer (score 2):

These two lines automatically resolved my dependency conflicts

Add
 `android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` in your application `gradle.properties` file.