# Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory)

Tags: android-studio

How to fix this issue. I'm try every possibility but doesn't solve this. Please help me.

> Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-23:19 to override.

Comment: Question already asked here and answer provided worked
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149963/7414213

Comment: @Yusuf folahan Thanks, But the answer did not work for me because i have lot of dependency which is not support androidx. and currently i don't want to migrate the project in androidx.

Comment: You have any idea to solve this problem please share with me. without migrate the dependency. it really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

When i had the problem with my project, i simply migrated from support to Androidx. You can check this link, hopefully it will be of help to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53201907/7414213

Comment: Thank you for your effort but still doesn't solve my problem.