# replace="android:appComponentFactory" in android application

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on my app.Everything was ok but i do not know why i got this error when i tried to run the application:

```
Execution failed for task ':inteligentestate:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-28:19 to override.
```

from the error suggestion i added `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` in my main application manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".application.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
```

When i run my app i got this error:

```
Task :inteligentestate:processDebugManifest FAILED
/mnt/main/Project/.../AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-29:19 Error:
    tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified
/mnt/main/Tutorial/Android/project/.../AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
```

I googled and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268865/android-x-toolsreplace-specified-at-line-for-attribute-but-no-new-value-spec) .
I'm not using androidX

This is my project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // Support
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${versions.supportLib}"

    // room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${versions.room}"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${versions.room}"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:${versions.room}"

    // Network
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${versions.gson}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${versions.retrofit}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${versions.retrofit}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${versions.interceptor}"

    //rx java
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${versions.rxAndroidVersion}"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${versions.rxJavaVersion}"

    //Other
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${versions.timber}"
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${versions.butterknife}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${versions.butterknife}"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${versions.dagger}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${versions.dagger}"

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation project(path: ':map')
}
```

And library dependancies:

```
dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${versions.constraintLayout}"
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLib}"
    api "com.android.support:support-v4:${versions.supportLib}"

    // Mapbox
    api "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:${versions.mapboxMapSdk}"
    api "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-localization-v7:${versions.mapboxPluginLocalization}"
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54149652/manifest-merger-failed-attribute-applicationappcomponentfactory-android-stu) anber mentioned that

> project has different versions of the same library

But i think my project's library is the same!!!

Comment: You have both AndroidX and legacy Android Support dependencies. Using the Jetifier?

Comment: What is Jetifier ? @laalto

Comment: Which one is  AndroidX Android Support dependencies? @laalto

Comment: Some library might have AndroidX as its dependencies transitively. Jetifier helps with the transition period between legacy support lib and androidx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680671/what-is-jetifier

Comment: use tools:remove="android:appComponentFactory"

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Android Studio => Refactor Menu => Migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's easy.

Go to your **application manifest** and at bottom you'll see **mergedManifest** option

navigate to **mergedManifest bottom** where it will tell your what you've error and in what file

> See you error closer. It's mostly error in our layout file that's why merged Manifest don't works

Hope so it will solve your error!!!

Answer (score -2):

please try  downgrade your gradle version  and restart Android studio

Comment: I am using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2` why i have to downgrade my gradle!!! @kishandungarani

Comment: Why should downgrade?

Comment: because some libraries can not support latest gradle version you should try